# Test_step returns no loss values

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, autoencoder

I have been working for some time with a VAE model based off of [this](https://keras.io/examples/generative/vae/)example, working with binary data so it has been modified.

Recently, the computing cluster I was working on suffered a fault and my most recent version of my script was lost. Here is a [gist](https://gist.github.com/callum-b/c682e54d4d9a3668aa4f58e4d92cac8a) with the full code that I am currently running on my local computer, and I've also included it below, and the data can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/nz6Sr3GL):

```
import csv
import sys
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import math
import os
import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Input, Embedding, Flatten, Reshape, Dropout, ReLU
from tensorflow.keras.regularizers import l1
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
import tensorflow.keras.callbacks as kcb

def split_train_test(mydata, test_ratio=0.2):
    msk = np.random.randn(len(mydata)) < 1-test_ratio
    train = mydata[msk]
    test = mydata[~msk]
    return train, test

class Sampling(layers.Layer):
    """Uses (z_mean, z_log_var) to sample z, the vector encoding a digit."""

    def call(self, inputs):
        z_mean, z_log_var = inputs
        batch = tf.shape(z_mean)[0]
        dim = tf.shape(z_mean)[1]
        epsilon = tf.keras.backend.random_normal(shape=(batch, dim))
        return z_mean + tf.exp(0.5 * z_log_var) * epsilon

def nll(y_true, y_pred):
    ## From Louis Tiao's post
    """ Negative log likelihood (Bernoulli). """

    # keras.losses.binary_crossentropy gives the mean
    # over the last axis. we require the sum

    return keras.backend.sum(keras.backend.binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred), axis=-1)

class VAE(keras.Model):
    ## FROM https://keras.io/examples/generative/vae/
    def __init__(self, encoder, decoder, **kwargs):
        super(VAE, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.encoder = encoder
        self.decoder = decoder
        self.total_loss_tracker = keras.metrics.Mean(name="loss")
        self.reconstruction_loss_tracker = keras.metrics.Mean(
            name="reconstruction_loss"
        )
        self.kl_loss_tracker = keras.metrics.Mean(name="kl_loss")

    @property
    def metrics(self):
        return [
            self.total_loss_tracker,
            self.reconstruction_loss_tracker,
            self.kl_loss_tracker,
        ]

    def train_step(self, data):
        if isinstance(data, tuple):
            data = data[0]
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            z_mean, z_log_var, z = self.encoder(data)
            reconstruction = self.decoder(z)
            ## BASE RECONSTRUCTION LOSS:
            # reconstruction_loss = tf.reduce_mean( keras.losses.binary_crossentropy(data, reconstruction) )
            ## ELBO RECONSTRUCTION LOSS: 
            reconstruction_loss = tf.reduce_mean( nll(data, reconstruction) )
            ## KULLBACK-LEIBLER DIVERGENCE (maybe?):
            kl_loss = -0.5 * (1 + z_log_var - tf.square(z_mean) - tf.exp(z_log_var))
            kl_loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.reduce_sum(kl_loss, axis=1))
            ## BASE TOTAL LOSS:
            total_loss = reconstruction_loss + kl_loss
        grads = tape.gradient(total_loss, self.trainable_weights)
        self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, self.trainable_weights))
        self.total_loss_tracker.update_state(total_loss)
        self.reconstruction_loss_tracker.update_state(reconstruction_loss)
        self.kl_loss_tracker.update_state(kl_loss)
        return {
            "loss": self.total_loss_tracker.result(),
            "reconstruction_loss": self.reconstruction_loss_tracker.result(),
            "kl_loss": self.kl_loss_tracker.result(),
        }
    
    def test_step(self, data):
        ## TENTATIVE CALL FUNCTION FOR VALIDATION DATA
        if isinstance(data, tuple):
            data = data[0]
        z_mean, z_log_var, z = self.encoder(data)
        reconstruction = self.decoder(z)
        ## BASE RECONSTRUCTION LOSS:
        # reconstruction_loss = tf.reduce_mean( keras.losses.binary_crossentropy(data, reconstruction) )
        ## ELBO RECONSTRUCTION LOSS: 
        reconstruction_loss = tf.reduce_mean( nll(data, reconstruction) )
        kl_loss = -0.5 * (1 + z_log_var - tf.square(z_mean) - tf.exp(z_log_var))
        kl_loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.reduce_sum(kl_loss, axis=1))
        ## BASE TOTAL LOSS:
        total_loss = reconstruction_loss + kl_loss
        return {
            "loss": total_loss,
            "reconstruction_loss": reconstruction_loss,
            "kl_loss": kl_loss,
        }
    

data = pd.read_csv("/my/dir/my_data.txt", sep="\t", header=None, index_col=0)
x_train, x_test = split_train_test(np.transpose(np.array(data, dtype="float32")))

## DEFINE AUTOENCODER PARAMS

input_size = x_train.shape[1]
hidden_1_size = math.ceil(0.5*input_size)
hidden_2_size = math.ceil(0.2*input_size)
hidden_3_size = math.ceil(0.08*input_size)
code_size = math.ceil(0.05*input_size)


dropout_rate = 0.2


## CREATE AUTOENCODER STRUCTURE FOR CATEGORICAL DATA

myactivation = "sigmoid"

input_data = Input(shape=x_train[1].shape)
hidden_1 = Dense(hidden_1_size, activation=myactivation)(input_data)
e_drop_1 = Dropout(dropout_rate)(hidden_1)
hidden_2 = Dense(hidden_2_size, activation=myactivation)(e_drop_1)
e_drop_2 = Dropout(dropout_rate)(hidden_2)
hidden_3 = Dense(hidden_3_size, activation=myactivation)(e_drop_2)

code_mean = Dense(code_size, name="code_mean")(hidden_3)
code_log_var = Dense(code_size, name="code_log_var")(hidden_3)
code = Sampling()([code_mean, code_log_var])

latent_inputs = Input(shape=(code_size,))

hidden_3_rev = Dense(hidden_3_size, activation=myactivation)(latent_inputs)
d_drop_1 = Dropout(dropout_rate)(hidden_3_rev)
hidden_2_rev = Dense(hidden_2_size, activation=myactivation)(d_drop_1)
d_drop_2 = Dropout(dropout_rate)(hidden_2_rev)
hidden_1_rev = Dense(hidden_1_size, activation=myactivation)(d_drop_2)
pre_output_data = Dense(input_size, activation=myactivation)(hidden_1_rev) 
output_data = ReLU(max_value=1.0)(pre_output_data) 

## TRAIN AUTOENCODER

encoder = Model(input_data, [code_mean, code_log_var, code], name="encoder")
decoder = Model(latent_inputs, output_data, name="decoder")


var_autoencoder = VAE(encoder, decoder)

var_autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adam', metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy()])

history = var_autoencoder.fit( x_train, x_train, epochs=1000, shuffle=True, validation_data=(x_test, x_test), 
                 callbacks=kcb.EarlyStopping(monitor="val_loss", patience=30, restore_best_weights=True) )
```

I wrote the test step myself, and used it to train my models for a few months earlier this year. However, now that I'm trying to run it again, it doesn't seem to return any meaningful values:

```
> Epoch 1/1000
127/127 [==============================] - 2s 9ms/step - loss: 187.9941 - reconstruction_loss: 187.8929 - kl_loss: 0.1011 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_reconstruction_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_kl_loss: 0.0000e+00
> Epoch 2/1000
127/127 [==============================] - 1s 8ms/step - loss: 154.8218 - reconstruction_loss: 154.8206 - kl_loss: 0.0012 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_reconstruction_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_kl_loss: 0.0000e+00
> Epoch 3/1000
127/127 [==============================] - 1s 8ms/step - loss: 154.5254 - reconstruction_loss: 154.5229 - kl_loss: 0.0025 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_reconstruction_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_kl_loss: 0.0000e+00
```

If there's an issue with my `test_step()`, it's possible that I had worked through it previously and simply didn't save the solution to my PC.

I'm currently using tensorflow 2.12.0 and Python 3.8.10

Why is it not returning any loss values currently?

Comment: I've just run your code (with above example), and it works fine. I'm using TF 2.12, what is yours?

Comment: @Innat I'm also on TF 2.12

Comment: Please share a colab gist.

Comment: @Innat added, but I'm not familiar with colab so it's in a github gist

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to also use metrics tracker for the validation (test) step. (I will leave out most of your code and only show the new code):

```py
class VAE(keras.Model):
    ## FROM https://keras.io/examples/generative/vae/
    def __init__(self, encoder, decoder, **kwargs):
        ...  # insert here your code!
        self.kl_loss_tracker = keras.metrics.Mean(name="kl_loss")  # this is already part of your code
        self.total_loss_tracker_val = keras.metrics.Mean(name="val_loss")
        self.reconstruction_loss_tracker_val = keras.metrics.Mean(
            name="val_reconstruction_loss"
        )
        self.kl_loss_tracker_val = keras.metrics.Mean(name="val_kl_loss")
    
    @property
    def metrics(self):
        return [
            self.total_loss_tracker,
            self.reconstruction_loss_tracker,
            self.kl_loss_tracker,
            self.total_loss_tracker_val,
            self.reconstruction_loss_tracker_val,
            self.kl_loss_tracker_val,
        ]

    def test_step(self, data):
        ...
        total_loss = reconstruction_loss + kl_loss
        self.total_loss_tracker_val.update_state(total_loss)
        self.reconstruction_loss_tracker_val.update_state(reconstruction_loss)
        self.kl_loss_tracker_val.update_state(kl_loss)
        return {
            "loss": total_loss,
            "reconstruction_loss": reconstruction_loss,
            "kl_loss": kl_loss,
        }
```

The reason to use two different trackers is that (I think) TF only calls the `reset_state()` method at the end of an epoch, and if you use the same tracker for training and test steps, you have the updated state of the training step in your validation step.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'll test this out as soon as I have time, which may be january